Threads disappearing without a trace
I have recently seen a couple of threads disappearing totally even from my inbox and achievement list, as if they never existed. What has happened? Shouldn't deleted posts be still visible in pink to users with 2000+ reputation? Shouldn't deleted account posts show up as "anonymous"?

Possibly related: Why are so many upvoted questions with upvoted answers being deleted recently? Deleted content does disappear from your inbox and may remove achievements (but you can still see your deleted questions or answers if you have 2k+ reputation).

But I cannot see the thread on which you commented my answer the last time just a couple of days ago. And I asked you to "put your money where your mouth is". Something about determinism, obviously.

You're presumably talking about the comments on this answer, which was moved to chat, which also removes all of it from your inbox. Only new replies in chat would be sent to your inbox. (And you can't see the "Comments have been moved to chat" comment, because that answer itself was deleted, as per the Q&A I linked to in my comment above).

But why cannot I see the thread directly, only through your links?

You should be able to see your deleted answers by clicking on "deleted answers" at the bottom of your answers, which should lead you here, which presumably contains that answer (I don't have access to that page for your account, but I see something similar for my account).

@NotThatGuy Or just put deleted:1 in the search box. Chat is a harder problem. Ive never figured out how to search in chat

NotThatGuy is correct, the two threads are about the same user. And you should be able to see them the way described in the comment thread to your question.
You can either follow this link or, sometimes easier to reach, just go on your user profile -> answers -> newest and you should see the two answers in question as well. I can, anyway.
Please give feedback whether this works for you.

Yes, I did find them. I just assumed that they should be visible straight away, wasn't aware of this method.
